# How to find the ID of the most outer element from click event using JQuery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-selectors

I am trying to get the id of a list item from a radio button click event. I have tried many notations but seem to stuck on this hurdle. Any help would be appreciated.

HTML:

```
<li class="option" id="100400" title=""> <!-- I NEED THE ID OF THIS LIST ITEM -->
    <h5 class="ui-widget-header">Option 1</h5>
    <font id="" class="repairDetails" alt="Repair Details" style=""></font>
    <font style=""></font><br />
    <label class="price">£49.99</label>
    <a class="ui-icon ui-icon-wrench dialog_but" title="View Product Detail" href="#" style="">View Product Detail</a>
    <div id="op1Dialog" class="dialog_content" title="" style="">
        <div class="products">
            <h1 class="ui-widget-header">Avaliable Bundle Options</h1>
            <font>You can customise this option below</font>
            <div class="pOptions">
                <h2 class="customOHeader"><a href="#">Handle</a></h2>
                <div>
                    <ul>
                        <button ID="Button1" class="handle-pre">
                            Add Handle Preferance
                        </button>
                    </ul>
                </div>

                <h2><a href="#">Blade Fittings</a></h2>
                <div>
                    <ul>
                        <li for="Radio1">
                            Clear Extratec Scuff Sheet
                            <input type="radio" id="Radio1" name="" value="" class="bladeCO"/> <!-- CLICK EVENT HAPPENS HERE -->
                        </li><br />
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div> 
        </div>
    </div>  
</li>
```

jQuery:

```
$('.bladeCO').click(function(){
    var option = $(this).closest('.option').attr('id');
});
```

Many thanks.

Comment: `font` tags? Really!! Does seem to work for me though -> [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/TvgvA/)

Comment: so you have one radio button.. does it work like a checkbox or something?

Comment: probably be better off with `li.option`, to make sure you get the li element, and not something else that perchance has the same class.

Comment: @LouisXIV - On the first freaking line of the code ?

Comment: I don't get what's not working.. it works fine here [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Dx9MD/)

Comment: I agree with @wirey - there is no problem here, the code should work.

Comment: Did you remember to wrap that in a `$(document).ready(function() { ... });`

Comment: I can see the code works in fiddle but somehow it fails in my project! I guess I am missing something fundamental here. Is it ok to post the full segment of HTML for you guys to have a look?

Comment: I put all the HTML into the fiddle and it works in fiddle but not in my code... So i guess its something else entirely ... Thank you very much for all the replies...

Comment: It should be `document.ready` as jsFiddle doesn't need that to work...

Comment: @uacyber - Do you read the comments and try the suggestions. Did you or did you not wrap your jQuery code with the document.ready function, as suggested 15 minutes ago?

Comment: I tried to edit the jquery code above but its not letting me. so here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ck4b2/323/ . I am off as the snow is comming down really badly, I'll continue once I'm at home. Thank you so much for all of your time guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this out:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.bladeCO').click(function(){
        var option = $($(this).parents("li.option")[0]).attr('id');

        console.log(option);
    });
});
```

The issue may be because of the rest of your code which is not shown here. There may be another `li` element nearby than the `parent`. Like this:

```
                    <ul>
                        <li for="Radio1">Clear Extratec Scuff Sheet
                        <input type="radio" id="Radio1" name="" value="" class="bladeCO"/> CLICK EVENT HAPPENS HERE</li><br />
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div> 
        </div>
    </div>    
</li>
<li class="option" id="some_other_id" title="">
    <h5 class="ui-widget-header">Option 1</h5>
```

Also, if it is working in jsFiddle and not in your code, it may be the `jquery` ready...

**Update**

This jsFiddle is working fine, seems to be issue with `jquery-ui` : http://jsfiddle.net/ck4b2/336/.

Comment: You do realize you could just use `first()`, `eq(0)` or a number of other functions instead of rewrapping with jQuery.

Comment: The issue is not HTML as the fiddle above proves that the notation returns the correct id. I think it might be something else...

Comment: @uacyber Can you try this?

Comment: So sorry for the late reply. I don't know why the jquery-ui : is causing the code to fail. But when I take the JQ-UI it all works fine. Have to figure out a way for them to work togather happily as I need both of them in this project. Thank you again for the reply.

Answer (score 1):

I'm changing my answer to reflect adeneo's idea of wrapping this code in a document ready function.

```
$(function(){
    $('.bladeCO').click(function(){
        var option = $(this).closest('li.option').attr('id');
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I have tried this as well. but the variable returns as 'undefined' ??

Comment: Something else must be going on with your setup, because it works for me. [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/brussell/3THEf/)